# Android canvas, how to draw something under an existing shape?

Tags: android, canvas, view

I know I can use this code to draw a line on the rectangle:

```
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 400, 400, paint);

paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 500, 500, paint);
```

And the canvas looks like this :

[image]

But now I want to draw the line under the rectangle **without exchange the order of their drawing**, and it should like :

[image]

How can I do that ?

**Can the canvas undo what has just been painted on it?**

or

**Does canvas have layers in it, which I can specify to draw on?**

Comment: You need to calculate the intersection and don't draw there

Comment: I thinks you should  draw two lines one from (0,0) to top left corner of rectangle and then draw rectangle ,and then draw new line from bottom right corner to (500,500)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CustomViews to draw the shape and existing shape or on Image

Comment: I know the `onDraw` gives a clean canvas when it's called, but i'm not using custom view, I just use `new Canvas(bitmap)`, maybe what I wonder is that whether canvas can undo what has just been painted on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by drawing two lines:

```
   paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 400, 400, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(400, 400, 500, 500, paint);
```